# Single Logout with ADFS

Tags: java, websphere, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

Trying to implement a Single Logout integration between IBM WebSphere as SP and ADFS as IdP: since SLO is not supported OOB by WebSphere as reported [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwbs_samlssosummary.html)  on bottom of the page, I am searching for a reference about parsing `SAMLRequest` (`LogoutRequest`) sent from IdP and building a `SAMLResponse` (`LogoutResponse`) from SP, side with Java code.

The client (SP) application is on WebSphere Commerce.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of SAML stacks for Java - [I need a SAML stack — now!](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

They are open source so you can see how it is implemented.

Even better would be to integrate the stack if possible. That way you don't have to handle SLO - the stack will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Liberty profile supports SAML single-logout out-of-box since 18.0.0.2 release, see step 17 in  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_config_saml_web_sso.html